# How can I have child div without background image from parent div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs: One parent, one its child.

Parent has background image:

```
.parent{
  background-image: url('urltoimage/img.png');
  z-index: 1;
 }
.child{
  z-index: 2;
 }
```

but parent background image is still covering the background of its child. I want that child doesnot have background image

I also tried with `z-index`, but no success.

Comment: Why would you even post something you think is the "most dumbest post ever"? At 2000+ rep you must have *some* idea that we're concerned with the quality of content posted here.

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup and more of the CSS? If the child is nested inside the parent, there is no reason I can think of why its background should not be showing... unless your child background has transparencies or the div is collapsed.

Comment: Remember to set the height if the children Div is empty.In fact you can debug it in chrome develop tool, on mouse right button(in the parent div)-> inspect element -> adjust the element height in right side : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no image for the child, nor is any background color for the child specified.
By inheritance property, the child inherits the parent attributes and overrides the parent attributes' values it specifies.

Your code could be something like this:

```
.parent{
  background-image: url('urltoimage/img.png');
  z-index: 1;
 }
.child{
   background-image: url('urltoimage/CHILD_IMAGE.png');
   // or you could specify background color
   z-index: 2;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are doing something wrong while writing the HTML part of the code but CSS looks fine.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
   </div>
</div>
```

Is this how you are doing it?  Also don`t forget to add height and width in your css.

Example: [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/osamayawar/fv3Qq/)

Comment: thanks, but i want that child div doesnot have background image, how can i do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "BACKGROUND OF ITS CHILD"?  - "but parent background image is still covering the background of its child.".

Are you talking about the Background-color?

Comment: no, as you see in my code, i am talking about background image

Comment: Leaving .child empty do not make sense, either add a background-color or background-image. What do you expect when you are leaving the .child class empty? 

Whats inside your <div class="child"></div>?

Answer (score 0):

If your child div has no background settings, it's natural that its' parent div background will show through. If you are trying to create the effect of cutting out the area of the child's div from the parent div. Then, you might have to use a different approach. One example might be to set the child's background to the same as the its' parents' parent's background. Otherwise, what has been mentioned about setting the dimensions and/or background of the child's div by others on this post will be your only recourse.

Here's a thought, can you use a .png image file for the parent's background-image that has a transparent area where the child div will be positioned?